# Extract single row per multi-column group from dataframe based on certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Assuming I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
 Group Setting Runtime Memory SomeOtherColumns
 A     X       102     105    ...
 A     X       107     80     ...
 A     Y       100     104    ...
 A     Y       101     82     ...
 B     X       10      50     ...
 B     X       11      51     ...
 B     X       8       52     ...
 B     Y       13      60     ...
 B     Y       14      61     ...
 B     Y       15      62     ...
 C     X       5       6      ...
 C     Y       6       7      ...
```

I would like to extract one row per `Group+Setting`, i.e., one row for `A+X`, `A+Y`, `B+X`, `B+Y`, `C+X`, and `C+Y`.
The extracted row should be the one with the lowest `Runtime` value for the given group.

Following the expected result:

```
 Group Setting Runtime Memory SomeOtherColumns ...
 A     X       102     105    ...
 A     Y       100     104    ...
 B     X       8       52     ...
 B     Y       13      60     ...
 C     X       5       6      ...
 C     Y       6       7      ...
```

Comment: The question that has been marked as duplicate states in its first sentence `I wish to (1) group data by one variable (State)`, yet I wanted to group by multiple variables.
But the answer of @docendo discimus works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` this would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group, Setting) %>% slice(which.min(Runtime))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   Group, Setting [6]
# Group Setting Runtime Memory SomeOtherColumns
#  <fct> <fct>     <int>  <int> <fct>           
# 1 A     X           102    105 ...             
# 2 A     Y           100    104 ...             
# 3 B     X             8     52 ...             
# 4 B     Y            13     60 ...             
# 5 C     X             5      6 ...             
# 6 C     Y             6      7 ...
```

Similarly, in `data.table` parlance:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[which.min(Runtime)], by = .(Group, Setting)]
```

or using the order:

```
unique(df[order(Runtime)], by = c("Group", "Setting"))
```